# How to create angular2 jwt token in angular2

Tags: angular

I need to create a jwt in  angular2. How do I do that?
I am using this for an api service.

```
 jwt_token = ?
```

I can create in python with no issue.

Comment: hit and run.....dude if you down vote provide an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Normally tokens are generated on the server-side !!
If you are creating them on client side, its easy to see your password!!**

Anyway, to answer your question:

Best way is to use an existing library, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

`npm install jsonwebtoken --save`

install its typings (if you use TypeScript)

`npm install @types/jsonwebtoken --save`

and use it like this:

```js
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

let token = jwt.sign({ anyObject: 'here..' }, 'your super secret password!!');
```

Comment: jsonwebtoken is meant to work with node not browser.. See here: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/317

Answer (score 0):

try to see this project: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

it's a module to deal with JWT token with angular2 with documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

@mxii is right, **generating jwt token client side exposes ur private key**.

If u want to do that anyway, use this: https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-JWT-generation